# PHP exploded didn't return array

Tags: php

I have some strings which contain `,` character and I need to explode them into array. For example there are two cases

```
    $str = 'Jack, Rose, John';
```

Or

```
    $str = 'Jack';
```

When I used this code to each case

```
    $formatted = str_replace(' ', '', $str); // Remove spaces
    $names = explode(',',$formatted); // Split strings to array
```

In first case, everything goes fine. Three name (Jack, Rose, John) are splitted into array that I can use.

```
    $str = 'Jack, Rose, John';
    $formatted = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    $names = explode(',',$formatted);
    foreach($names AS $name)
    {
            // Get user from database using $name.
            // Everything works just fine.
    }
```

But in the second case I didn't get an array. When I used foreach it just return empty string for each loop.

```
    $str = 'Jack';
    $formatted = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    $names = explode(',',$formatted);
    foreach($names AS $name)
    {
            // Get user from database using $name.
            // Return error because $name empty ?!
    }
```

I appreciate your answers to tell me why this happened.

Comment: what is wrong ? - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8a4aa0dcc99090d1b34355dcf4c627fb316aacd

Comment: Code seems to work.

Comment: 'jack' Does not have a comma so this is expected behavior.

Comment: it works in all case. i didn't get any error in your code.

Comment: Note that by doing `$formatted = str_replace(' ', '', $str);` you also remove spaces in the names. So **Van Gogh** would become **VanGogh**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test code :

```
$str1 = 'Jack, Rose, John';
$str2 = 'Jack';

$formatted1 = str_replace(' ', '', $str1);
$names1 = explode(',', $formatted1);

$formatted2 = str_replace(' ', '', $str2);
$names2 = explode(',', $formatted2);

foreach($names1 as $name){echo $name . "<br/>";}
foreach($names2 as $name){echo $name . "<br/>";}
```

Output :

```
Jack
Rose
John
Jack
```

This is how I've tested your code and it seems to work fine.
If it still doesn't work fine for you, try adding a comma at the end of your string. 
Though it will add an empty array entry at the end of your array so I'd recommend using array_pop before your foreach.

Here's an example :

```
$str = 'Jack, Rose, John';
$str .= ','; //Adding a comma

$formatted = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$names = explode(',', $formatted);
array_pop($names); //Popping the last empty entry

foreach($names as $name){
    //Do your thing here
}
```

Comment: thanks, add a comma to the last and work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to used str_replace method. `explode(',', $str)` will help to form array from giving string, because it store data in array form even for single value.
`$str = 'Jack, Rose, John';
$names = explode(',', $str);
var_dump($names);`